# Build system for project that uses C and Haskell

Tags: c, haskell, cmake, cabal

I am working on a project that uses C and Haskell.  Currently, I am using CMake to build a C shared library and cabal to build a Haskell executable.  Is there a more unified way to do this?  Can I invoke cabal from the Makefile generated by CMake or is there a way to build the C library directly from Cabal?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a C library?  You can specify C source files directly via Cabal, and they will be compiled and linked into your project.

Comment: I am working on a programming language that compiles source to C as an intermediate language.  The parser and C code generator are written in Haskell.  The C intermediate code is piped to the systems C compiler which links against the shared library.  So the library and executable are seperate entities; I do not need to link the haskell stuff with the library.

Comment: You could specify the Custom build mode in your cabal file, and simply run cmake at the appropriate time during the cabal build (probably this is either before or after your haskell package is built). See the documentation for [`UserHooks`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.20.0.1/docs/Distribution-Simple.html).

Comment: You just need to create custom commands in CMake to invoke Cabal. See: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html

Answer (score 1):

CMake could also do what you want. It does however duplicate lots of the functionality of cabal. So you could call cabal from whatever build tool you choose to use (for cmake, using a custom command, for makefiles, it's pretty self-explanatory), build binaries directly (see cabal build -v).

See [Is it possible to use cmake for Haskell projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969616/is-it-possible-to-use-cmake-for-haskell-projects).